# Can't disable UIBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uibarbuttonitem

I'm instantiating my UIBarButtonItem as a property of my class:

```
var copyBarButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem {
    return UIBarButtonItem(title: "Copy", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Bordered, target: self, action: "copyButtonClicked:")
}
```

The button is added to my toolbar:

```
var toolbarButtonItems:Array<UIBarButtonItem> = [spacer, self.copyBarButtonItem]
self.setToolbarItems(toolbarButtonItems, animated: false)
```

All works fine. The only problem is that I can't disable the button!

I've tried:

```
self.copyBarButtonItem.enabled = false
```

No luck. I've tried the `setEnabled` method, but that doesn't seem to exist for UIBarButtonItem.

Comment: You cannot disable `UIBarButtonItem`s.

Comment: In the Mail app on the iPhone, when clicking 'Edit', the 'Move' and 'Trash' toolbar items are disabled. How to they achieve that?

Comment: Setting the tint colour to grey and not responding to the target actions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `computed property`.Each time your `self.copyBarButtonItem` will give different instance.Use instead

```
var copyBarButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Copy", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Bordered, target: self, action: "copyButtonClicked:");
```

you need to define as `stored properties`.Stored Properties are just variable in `swift`